# AWS throws 503 error when using HttpContext.Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Good day Ma'am/Sirs, I'm having an issue in my c# code when I deploy it in AWS.Below is the code.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   if (HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority != "sample.com")
   {
      HttpContext.Response.Redirect("https://" + HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority + "/Error/PageNotFound#!/Index");
   }
}
```

When I add the `HttpContext.Response.Redirect` in my code and update my site in `AWS` it always throws me a `503` error. My code is working if it's not there but I have to include it because I don't want my website to be accessed by its public IP. Is there anyway to fix this? Thanks in advance